# Can the standard map $\Sigma \Omega X \to X$ be a homotopy equivalence?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, loop-spaces

The question is in the title : are there spaces X such that the adjoint of the identity on the loop space $\Omega X$, i.e. $\Sigma\Omega X \to X$, is a homotopy equivalence ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If $X$ is such a space (a CW complex, say), then it must be a suspension $\Sigma Y$ (as it is the suspension of $y :=\Omega X$). The James splitting gives
$$\Sigma \Omega \Sigma Y \simeq \bigvee_{n=1}^\infty \Sigma Y^{\wedge n},$$
the wedge of suspensions of smash products, so under your assumption $\Sigma \Omega \Sigma Y \overset{\sim}\to \Sigma Y$ it follows that $\Sigma Y^{\wedge n} \simeq *$ for all $n > 1$. In particular, by the Kunneth theorem $Y$ must have the homology of a point, and in particular be path-connected. But then $X=\Sigma Y$ must be simply-connected, and also have the homology of a point: therefore it is contractible.

Comment: There's a step I don't see. If you take $Y=M(\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z,n)$, $n\geq 2$, $Y^{\wedge 2}$ is contractible since $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z\otimes \mathbb Q/\mathbb Z=0=Tor_1^{\mathbb Z}(\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z,\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z)$, isn't it?

Comment: The $Tor_1$ isn't zero: There's an exact sequence
$Tor_1(\mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow Tor_1(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\otimes \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}\otimes \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$. The right- and leftmost terms are 0, so the Tor is just $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @AchimKrause OMG, I took an injective module for a flat one!

Comment: In general, a map that induces isos on homology with field cofficients induces isos on integral homology. A quick rundown:
For $A\rightarrow B\rightarrow C$ a short exact sequence of abelian groups, if it works for two of these coefficients, it works for the third - that's the five-lemma. Start from $\mathbb{F}_p$ to inductively prove it for all $\mathbb{Z}/p^n$. Then it also follows for their colimit, $\mathbb{Z}/p^{\infty}$. But $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ decomposes into copies of $\mathbb{Z}/p^{\infty}$, so we're done by  $\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @AchimKrause: Maybe I should know this, but what exactly does the notation $\mathbb{Z}/p^\infty$ mean?

Comment: @GregFriedman One description is as all of the fractions where the denominator is a power of $p$ inside $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$. Equivalently, you can think of it as all of the $p^n$th roots of unity in $\mathbb{C}$ as you let $n$ vary. Does this help?

Comment: To add a third description (which is the one I use in my comment): If you embed $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/p^{n+1}$, sending $1$ to $p$, you basically add in $1/p$ of the generator. $\mathbb{Z}/p^\infty$ is defined as the colimit over this sequence of maps, so it is filtered by cyclic subgroups of order $p^n$, each of which is $p$ times the next. That connects directly to both of Sean's perspectives. If you're familiar with how towers in the Adams spectral sequence encode cyclic groups of order $p^n$, the right intuition here is a tower that extends infinitely far down.

Comment: Thanks, that all makes sense - I'd just never seen that particular notation before.